# Social share specific parts of a page

Tags: wordpress, socialshare

I have a question concerning social sharing.

I have a page with several toggles, and inside each toggle I'd like to have a few social buttons to allow sharing each paragraph.

In regards to that, how do I go about telling each social button exactly what to share (i.e. image and text/(description)?

This is a wordpress website.

Comment: What social networks do you want to use for sharing?

Comment: Facebook, google plus and twitter